# Selenium Python - How to Identify an Image button element by src or alt?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click on an image button but the element does not contain an id or a name it only has a src and an alt

```
img src="/images/bonuscard.png" alt="Card Icon"
```

So how can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this HTML :

```
img src="/images/bonuscard.png" alt="Card Icon"
```

You can construct an xpath like :

```
//img[@src='/images/bonuscard.png']
```

or

```
//img[@alt='Card Icon']
```

or

```
//img[@src='/images/bonuscard.png' and @alt='Card Icon']
```

in code, you could use it like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='/images/bonuscard.png' and @alt='Card Icon']").click()
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//img[@src='/images/bonuscard.png' and @alt='Card Icon']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below XPath,

```
//img[contains(@src,'bonuscard.png')]

//img[@src='/images/bonuscard.png']

//img[@src='/images/bonuscard.png' and @alt='Card Icon']
```

**Code**

```
imge = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'bonuscard.png')]")
imge.click()
```

Using `explicitWait`

```
 imge = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//img[contains(@src,'bonuscard.png')]")))
 imge.click()
```

**imports**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```